# Проблемная архитектура библиотеки .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура, библиотека

[image: сейчас моя "архитектура" выглядит так]

В последнее время я углубился в разработку своей библиотеки для надежной передачи данных по протоколу UDP. Хотя код пишеться пока что без особых проблем, я столкнулся с проблемой в архитектуре и структуре проекта. Я стремлюсь создать небольшую, но расширяемую и понятную библиотеку. К сожалению, нет магической формулы или статьи, которая бы решала мою конкретную проблему.

Моя библиотека содержит множество внутренних модулей, которые я связываю между собой и дополняю в ICEClient и ICEServer, особенно в области надежной отправки данных. Основные публичные классы - клиент и сервер - используют эти модули. Так же я сделал две папки, которые можно увидеть на скриншоте: ICE.Core и ICE.Traffic.

Папка ICE.Core содержит независимые компоненты, такие как логирование, DNS и базовый транспорт (обычная асинхронная обертка над UDP). Папка ICE.Traffic содержит связанные классы для сериализации и десериализации пакетов в байты и обратно. Этот модуль(ICE.Traffic) используется в ICEClient и ICEServer, а также я хочу, чтобы пользователи моей библиотеки имели доступ к таким классам, как Packet и Data. Именно поэтому я решил вынести папку ICE.Traffic отдельно от ICE.Core.

Я задаюсь вопросом, правильно ли я делаю? Есть ли ресурсы, которые описывают похожие ситуации и методы их решения? Я хочу создать библиотеку, которая не будет перегружена тысячей интерфейсов, но и не будет слишком простой.

Comment: Серебряной пули тут нет, каждый распоряжается своей архитектурой так, как ему удобно. Я бы разбил проект на 3 проекта. 1) Общие файлы для клиента и сервера (Core сборка), 2) Сервер, 3) Клиент.

Comment: В таком случае где мне впихнуть Traffic? Я ведь уточнил что хочу что бы пользователь библиотеки имел неполный доступ к этому модулю. Пихать его в Core будет не лучшей идеей?

Comment: Так у вас клиент и сервер будут ссылаться на YourLib.Core, в которой будут лежать все основные классы для работы, никто не запрещает сделать эти классы не Internal, а Public

Comment: В Core я засунул только Internal классы. Проект или папка Core будет доступна только внутри проекта. А вот Traffic я не могу запихнуть в Core так как его классы могут быть публичными. Так что придеться делать отдельный проект для него? Что бы пользователь так же как и Client и Server  могли получить доступ к Traffic через ICENet.Traffic?

Comment: `Проект или папка Core будет доступна только внутри проекта` почему? Core - это ядро, которое должно предоставлять базовый функционал или интерфейсы для того чтобы поверх одевать на него новую конкретизированную логику. `В Core я засунул только Internal классы` зачем? Весь смысл ядра в публичных абстракциях и базовой реализации

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Кажется мне придётся полностью пересмотреть и переделать текущую архитектуру. Есть какие-то 'шаблоны' для создания архитектуры для библиотеки? Например я слышал об Onion архитектуре, но кажется она для .asp приложений?

Comment: у вас проект не связанный с фреймворками, по этому самый лучший шаблон это тот, который просто будет удобен и логичен без лишних заморочек KISS